# Change pivot point to selected point

Tags: modeling, transforms, coordinates

In the attached picture, that the model is in the center of the point. I want to change from pivot point to point, where I want to picture it.
In Maya 2017 Student version works like this, when it is possible to change with the D keypad. 
Blender is so possible?

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the pivot point position, enter in *Edit* mode, select the vertice where you want the pivot point to be, press <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor To Selected*, go back in *Object* mode, then, in the bottom horizontal menu bar, in the *Pivot Point* dropdown menu, select *3D Cursor*.

[image]